# Evaluating $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2k+1)^5}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I want to evaluate $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2k+1)^5}$  to prove an integral result, how could I start? Any tips are appreciated

Comment: IIRC you can evaluate the alternating series $\sum_k (-1)^kk^{-5}$, for examples with the aid of selected Fourier series. This one is unknown in closed form (but trivially can be written using the zeta function). Even when the exponent is three. Look up [Apery's constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ap%C3%A9ry%27s_constant).

Comment: I think [this answer by Ethan](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/664314/721644) might help you.

Comment: [Maybe this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3062262/721644).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints:

$$1.0369=\zeta(5):=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^5}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{(2k)^5}+ \sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{1}{(2k+1)^5}$$

Can you finish from here?

Comment: Result is $\frac{31}{32} \zeta(5)$