Evaluating the odd part of an infinite series
Let's consider the following sequence
$$
a_n = \begin{cases} 0, \quad n = 2k, \, k \in \mathbb{Z} \\ \frac{1}{n^4}, \quad n = 2k+1, \, k \in \mathbb{Z} \end{cases}.
$$
I would like to compute the following series
$$
S = \sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n.
$$
I know that
$$
\zeta(4) = \frac{\pi^4}{90},
$$
and I assume that
$$
S = \frac{\pi^4}{96},
$$
however I don't know how to obtain that result. I would appreaciate any help.

So, you want $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(2k+1)^4}$. If you take $\zeta(4)=\pi^4/90$ as given, then the method used here for the $\zeta(5)$ analogue should suffice: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3882414/evaluating-sum-k-0-infty-frac12k15?noredirect=1

Hint: $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty  x_k = \sum_{k=0}^\infty  x_{2k} + \sum_{k=0}^\infty  x_{2k+1}$$ when the series converge.
